# Generating a standard deviation plot from a row in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jfreechart, standard-deviation

I am trying to create a `JTable` that I can be able to click on a row and it will display a standard deviation curve. Here is what my `JTable` looks like right now.

[image]

So for example, the standard deviation for the string `screen saver, action->login, login->disclaimer, ok` would look like this (I plotted it in excel)

[image]

So my question is #1 is this possible and #2 if so then how?

Comment: I think you mean Histogram, not standard deviation.

Comment: yeah this graph is a histogram

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ChartFactory.createHistogram()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.html#createHistogram%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.jfree.data.xy.IntervalXYDataset,%20org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) with an `IntervalXYDataset` such as `HistogramDataset` might be a suitable choice. `HistogramDemo1`, seen among the statistical charts in the [JWS demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html), is an example. You can determine which row was clicked using a `ListSelectionListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12306104/230513). You can retrieve the required values from your `TableModel` using `getValueAt()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731782/230513).