# getting a value from a previous loop to use in the current loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

How do I use a value from the previous iteration in my current loop? I am generating a `double [] v` and want to do `v - w` where w is the value of v in the previous iteration. Obviously I need to implement subtraction for 2 arrays.

```
if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) 
                {
                    double[] v = new double[uaCount.get(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0)).singleValues.size()];
                    int i = 0;
                    for(Long j : uaCount.get(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0)).singleValues) 
                    {
                      v[i++] = j.doubleValue();
                    }
                    double [] w, r;
                    //implement r = v-w
                    System.out.println(String.valueOf(uaCount.get(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(),0)).singleValues));
                    dataset.addSeries("Histogram",r, 1000, 0, 120000);  
                }
```

the purpose of this is to add a new dataset to my histogram while getting rid of the previous one. Now that I think about this more though, subtracting the values will give me different answers right?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: use lists, make your life easier

Comment: You've asked a [series of duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2007843/user2007843) on this topic going back to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16085734/230513). I've cited several complete examples. As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16176221/230513), you can "Replace the entire dataset in the plot." Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach. Use a _small_ `TableModel` having a _few_ rows and columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I use a value from the previous iteration in my current loop?

Just save the loop's current value as `previous` as the last line in the end of the loop.
In your first line of the loop when you re-enter, `previous` has the previous value

Answer (score 1):

declare a variable outside your loop to hold it

```
int val;
int prev;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    //do stuff with val
    ...
    prev = val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your explanation your reuirment is to do something like:

```
for(initialization;condition;increment){
curr[i] = i;//holds your current ittration value
if(prev != null){
//do some operation
//these extra things can also be done by cure[i-1] instead of using extra variable just    //check if i>0 then get the previous value from your curr array and perform operation //accordingly
}
prev = curr[i];
}
```

Approach 2: As suggested by other users you can make use of collection framework which will be more simpler.